# How can I configure Chrome so that it autofills passwords without me having to click on the password field first?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, passwords, productivity, auto-form-fill

In some password forms, I have to click on the password field first, then click on the save password to complete the field. Example:

[image]

How can I configure Chrome so that it autofills passwords without me having to click on the password field first?

I use Chrome on Microsoft Windows.

Comment: In my experience what you see is a function of the Website and not the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [John](https://superuser.com/users/1079976/john)  [commented](https://superuser.com/questions/1716509/how-can-i-configure-chrome-so-that-it-autofills-passwords-without-me-having-to-c#comment2648170_1716509), that depends on the website. Chrome on Windows doesn't seem to have any options or extensions so that it autofills passwords without the user having to click on the password field first.